# Mock a function inside other function

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I'm trying to test a class, but when I try to run the test I get the error `ReferenceError: document is not defined`. The error occurs when the test tries to execute the paint() function, inside the makeMove() method. I think this is because the code tries to run a function that manipulates the DOM and Jest doesn't understand.

player.test.js

```
import { Player } from "./player.js"

describe("Test the class Player", ()=>{
    test("Check the method makeMove()", ()=>{
        const player = new Player();
        player.makeMove();
        exportAllDeclaration(player).toBeLessThan(101);
    });
});
```

player.js

```
import { myCoordinates } from "./gameboard.js"
import { Ship } from "./ship.js"

var attackPoints = [];
export var myShip4 = new Ship(4, 0, false);
export var myShip3 = new Ship(3, 0, false);
export var myShip2 = new Ship(2, 0, false);
export var myShip1 = new Ship(1, 0, false);

export class Player{
    makeMove(){
        //Make automatic moves for the computer player
        var move = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        while(move==0){
            move = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
        }
        for(let i=0; i<attackPoints.length; i++){
            if(attackPoints[i]==move){
                move = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                i=0;
                while(move==0){
                    move = Math.floor(Math.random()*100);
                }
            }
        }
        attackPoints.push(move);
        for(let i=0; i<myCoordinates.length; i++){
            if(myCoordinates[i]==move){ 
                if(i==0 || i==1 || i==2 || i==3){
                    myShip4.hit();
                }
                if(i==4 || i==5 || i==6){
                    myShip3.hit();
                }
                if(i==7 || i==8){
                    myShip2.hit();
                }
                if(i==9){
                    myShip1.hit();
                }
                const audio = new Audio("sound.mp3");
                audio.play();
            }
        }
        this.paint(move);
        const attack = new Gameboard();
        const issAllSunk = attack.isAllSunk(myShip1, myShip2, myShip3, myShip4);
        if(issAllSunk){
            const audioFailure = new Audio("failure.wav");
            audioFailure.play();
            const game = new Gameboard();
            game.gameOver();
        } 
        return move;   
    }
    paint(move){
        document.getElementById(move).style.backgroundColor="#fca5a5";
    }
}
```

I looked for ways to mock the paint() function, but I couldn't. I would like to know how to make the paint() function not actually execute when running the makeMove() method test.

Comment: Is your paint function executed on a Worker or something similar that can't have access to the DOM ?

Comment: My paint() function has access to the DOM and works perfectly when the code is executed. Only when I run the test do I get this error.

Comment: The test doesn't have access to the DOM, because of that I want to moke the paint() function.

Comment: Well that is why you haven't access thé document object no ?

Comment: Yes, I want help to mock the function paint()

Comment: In your test do you want to actually test the effect of paint on the DOM or you just want to see if paint() it was actually called ?

Comment: I just want to call the paint() function, I don't need to test the DOM events.

Comment: Ok well, maybe you could just check if the Document is null directly in your paint function, like that : 
if (document) 
    document.getElementById(move).style.backgroundColor="#fca5a5";

Not ideal, but its a solution.

Comment: Doing this, in the command line "if(document)" the test returns the error "ReferenceError: document is not defined".

Comment: Or how about you set up Jest to handle DOM? https://jestjs.io/docs/tutorial-jquery

Answer (score 0):

When you mock your method `paint`, it does not have access to the DOM (and so the document object is null).

So maybe you could just modify your `paint` method a bit :

```
paint(move) 
{
    if (typeof(document) != "undefined")
        document.getElementById(move).style.backgroundColor="#fca5a5";
}
```

It's not ideal, because you should not modify your function to make your test working but... It's a solution because the method will be called in your test and you will be able to check it number of execution with jest.

Comment: Doing this, in the command line "if(document)" the test returns the error "ReferenceError: document is not defined". The test don't understand what the word "document" is.

Comment: Ok, so you can do : if typeof(document) != "undefined" instead